# Is it against Admob policies to load an ad and hide it

Tags: android, admob

I have  a RecyclerView in my activity that's populated by a certain list. And the list (RecyclerView) is updated any time the user clicks on any item in the RecyclerView.

Sometimes the list is empty. So there's an Admob ad just above the said RecyclerView. I load the ad in `onCreate()`.

So if the list (RecyclerView) is empty, I hide the ad else I display the ad. The reason for this hiding and unhiding is because I read that it's against admob policies to show an ad on an empty page.

Please is there anything wrong with this hiding and unhiding?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about policy and not really about programming. Only Admob customer service can answer your question.

Comment: @Enzokie Admob/Adsense normally don't reply emails. Also there're Google employees that answer Admob/Adsense tagged questions here.

Comment: Yes I am aware that they are Google employees however this does not mean that the question will become on topic here. See also [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746).

Comment: Here is a portion of the meta post : *Oh sure, there might be some intrepid soul who has sailed these waters before, and come out alive. They might even be able to offer some insight. **There might even be the occasional employee** wandering these hallowed halls. But **We're not** Google, Facebook or Apple Customer Service:*

Comment: @X09 there is no policy of showing ad on empty page. Refer to this link to read about disallowed policies. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287 . Having said that you don't want to hide and show ad... Just create Ad on load and on refresh method of recycleview if count is > 0 then only call load method

Comment: @AmodGokhal, Thanks for your information. Please can you take a look at the "Ads should not be placed on screens that don’t offer any content" section of https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2936217?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287 . That was where I got the idea about showing an ad an an empty page.

Comment: What Google is trying to avoid is that the user gets confused between content and the ad. (they want to avoid "invalid clicks"). So Having a simple blank screen with an Ad confuses the user and goes against Google's policies. So in X09's case, having just the Ad on a blank screen goes against Google's policies. His question is valid (check my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm well aware of Google's policies because I've worked 5 years as a publisher so here's the answer to your question:

It depends on what you mean by hiding.

- If you mean loading the ad and then hidding it. Then yes it goes against Google's policies
- If you never load the ad and never make a request to Google then you are following Google's policies

In sum Google doesn't want the impression to be counted if the ad is not displayed.

**Answering specifically your question:** If the Ad code is onCreate and then you hide it goes against Google's policies because the advertiser is getting the "impression" but he will never have the chance to get the "click" (influencing some advertiser's metrics such as the CTR). If the advertiser has a CPM campaign he will pay for the impression..

PS: If you start getting a lot of clicks from those ads I can assure you that not only Google will reply but they will start trying to push other products

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please what do you suggest? I mean how do I remove an ad from a page that's now empty but wasn't empty as at the time the ad was loaded?

Comment: I don't know exactly your code but here's what I would do (the principle). If the RecycleView is empty I would write something like: "Couldn't load your content", or "Info not available" etc... and then  Iwould mark the ad it as "advertisement" (a small TextView saying "advertisement/ad" above or below the ad). That wouldn't be against Google's policies and you could have the ad. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the ad is till there, right? I mean the user is still seeing the ad, right?

Comment: @Ginggas Is it allowed to hide an ad after a certain time (eg. after 30s)? I'm displaying a native ad over an album art from a song and i would like to hide the ad. Does the ad need to be visible for a specific time to get counted as an impression?

Comment: @VinceVD Ad Manager counts an impression each time a creative is downloaded in the user's device and has begun to load. That means if you hide it after X seconds you are not following Google's policies. I've seen some apps and websites hiding it after X seconds (undetected) but if Google detects it, the app will get some sort of penalty for not respecting Google's policies.

Comment: @Ginggas and what if i don't request another ad after hiding? I always use one ad request only. Or is just hiding not allowed? Can't find anything about it in google policies which is really vague to be honest.

Comment: @VinceVD the advertiser is paying to get the advertisement on your page/screen. You cannot hide/remove/etc... They are actually very clear: "(avoid) Hiding ad units at anytime (e.g., display:none), unless you're implementing a responsive ad unit! " https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en However as I told you many people get away with it. Please vote for this answer if you are satisfied with it